# Read a very long line of text C#

Tags: c#

I want to read a very long line of text using C#. The length of the line is about 100000 chars. I am using StreamReader.ReadLine() method. I also want to write this long string to a file. One of them or both are not working properly. I could only write 99328 characters to a file.
How can I read and write a very long line of text using  C#?

Comment: What does "Not working properly" mean?  Exceptions?
What exactly do you need to do?
Do you need to have the entire line in memory at once?
Post the code you DO have.

Comment: 100k chars should pose no big problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you did not close your output buffer and it's not completing the file write.

Consider using
File.ReadAllText

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx

and File.WriteAllText

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are probably failing to call .Flush() on your output stream.